# remove section from customer dashboard

Tags: remove, section

iam very beginner in magento2 so how can i remove this section of page content

[image]

Thank you .

Comment: Please let me know which is this section. I assuming order listing section Right?

Comment: it's address listing section

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code in your custom theme file.

> app/design/frontend/Your_VendorName/Your_ThemeName/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_address_index.xml

Below code add your in above file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="address_grid" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**`Thanks.`**

Comment: still had same problem :(